# How to add a div element to the wrap container without pushing down the other elements

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a carousel but after I remove the element from the end of the div list and apply it to the beginning it only moves the other element down without occupying the space at the beginning of the list. Please see if you can aid me in this matter.

The code is : use the button to initiate the carousel.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#but").click(function(){
        $(".slides").animate({left: "+=170"},2000);
        //$('.wrap div').last().before$('.wrap div').first(;
        timer=setInterval(function() {
            //$(".wrap div:first-child").before($(".wrap div:last-child"))
            $( ".wrap div:first-child" ).before($( ".wrap div:last-child" ));
        },2000);
    });
});
</script>
<style>
.wrap
{
border:1px solid red;   
width:1000px;   
overflow:hidden;
height:100px;   

}
.slides
{
width:150px;
height:150px;
border:1px solid #C6F;  
margin-left:2px;
margin-right:2px;
float:left;
margin-top:2px;
margin-bottom:2px;  
text-align:center;
position:relative;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="slides">1</div>
    <div class="slides">2</div>
    <div class="slides">3</div>
    <div class="slides">4</div>
    <div class="slides">5</div> 
  </div>
</div>
<button id ="but">hello</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: jquery-1.3.2.js, really? You should think about update it

Answer (score 0):

There might be better ways, but perhaps this will get you started:

```
$("#but").click(function () {
    timer = setInterval(function () {
        $(".slides").animate({
            left: "+=170"
        }, 2000);
        $(".wrap div:first-child").before($(".wrap div:last-child"));
        $(".slides").animate({
            left: "-=170"
        }, 1);
    }, 2010);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't animate just one way. You are adding 170 pixel and never subtracting them.
You need to move it left right away as you insert it to the front of the list, and slowly animate it into view

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#but").click(function(){
        //$('.wrap div').last().before$('.wrap div').first(;
        timer=setInterval(function() {
            //$(".wrap div:first-child").before($(".wrap div:last-child"))
            $(".slides").animate({left: "-=170"},0);
            $(".slides").animate({left: "+=170"},2000);
            $( ".wrap div:first-child" ).before($( ".wrap div:last-child" ));
        },2000);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) When animation finishes all slides has style="left:170px" you need set it to 0

2) If you wish to change divs on click then you should use setTimeout and set time interval little bigger then in animation, otherwise it wouldn't work sometimes (kind of race condition between last animation tick and zeroing).

3) 170px is too big it shold be 155px.

div_width 150px +  border 1px + margin (from left)  2px + margin (from right) 2px.